# Editing WordPress Menu without changing Core Files

Tags: html, wordpress, menu

What is the best way to change the HTML structure of your WordPress menu (wp_nav_menu) function without editing the core files. There is an extra  that i'd like to add into html structure. Can someone please offer any suggestions on how to best do this.

Thanks

My apologies, I should have included the HTML code as a reference point. Basically, I'd like to enclose the  tags in a set of spans. ()

```
<nav id="access">
    <ul id="menu-sample-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-198"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/health-care-professional/">Health Care Professional</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-197" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-197"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/web-designer/">Web Designer</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-199" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-199"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/construction-worker/">Construction Worker</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you need to add? Have you read the [WordPress Menu User Guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide)?

Comment: I just updated my question to include the code I'm working with. I'd like to enclose the anchor tags in a span. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom walker as described in the Wordpress Codex for [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function) to change how a menu is rendered, without modifying the core files. Other parameters like `$before`, `$after`, `$link_before`, `$link_after` and `$items_wrap` may provide enough customization for your needs as well.

If you just need to add `<span>` tags around the rendered `<a>` tags you should be able to use the `before` and `after` parameters instead of implementing an custom walker class.

For instance when calling `wp_nav_menu()` in a theme file:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'before' => '<span>', 'after' => '</span>'));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Lee for the reference. I'll be reading up on that. In the meantime, I've included the actual code that I'd like to edit.

Comment: Also take a look at [Custom Usage](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker#General_Menu_Example) section of the [Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) documentation

Comment: Hey all, I've had a chance to familiarize myself with the custom walker classes. In the end, where exactly would I declare this class?

Comment: Thx for the additional info. I've read over the Custom Walker classes but could still use some assistance with implementation. For example, I found the walker class in nav-menu.php but am unsure how exactly to implement it. Again, I'm looking to add span tags around the <a href...> in my HTML mark up. Thx

Comment: You can declare the class in your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Thanks Lee. For testing purposes, I declared the walker class in my functions.php using the sample code from the WordPress codex. I called my wp_nav_menu function in my header but I think I'm not implementing it right. Could you please offer some additional guidance. <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary_nav','walker' => new Walker_Custom_Menu() )); ?>

Answer (score 0):

See this post: http://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/

What specifically would you like to add? Custom containers or an extra li -item for example..? Maybe you could post an example of the structure.

Comment: Hey Ketri, I'm looking simply to add <span> tags around the <a href> in my html without editing the core files. I'm just learning about the Custom Walker classes but could use some assistance on implementation. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by creating a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php). In your child theme you can put all the template-files that need the new menu. Because if you directly edit the files in the parent theme they will be lost, when the theme get's updated.

If you need to change some general stuff, then just call the function like my_nav_menu and copy just the wp_nav_menu function out of function.php in the core directory. Then just edit the stuff you need to change and also rename the function to your function name in the template-files of your child theme. So rename wp_nav_menu to my_nav_menu.

Hope that help's you :)

Comment: Thank you for the assistance and the advice was most helpful. Is it possible to do what I'm looking to do without creating a child theme?

Comment: Do you use a wordpress theme or a custom one? Because like I said you can also edit directly the theme files of your parent theme but the changes will get lost, when you update the theme. However you then really need to work with the walkers I guess like leepowers said.

Comment: Hi Mainz, I use a custom theme.